# In javascript or jquery, what's the best way of running a function whose function name and parameters come in a json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm receiving the following object for example:

```
var object = {
    functions: {
        0: 'myFunction',
        1: 'alert'
    },
    parameters: {
        0: {
            0: 'Testing myFunction...'
        },
        1: {
            0: 'Testing alert...'
        }
    }
}
```

After receiving `object` variable I want to run all the functions specified with the corresponding parameters.

That is, after receiving the object I want the following to happen:

```
myFunction('Testing myFunction');
alert('Testing alert');
```

Is there an elegant way of handling this or is stringconversion into eval the way to go? Some other methods I don't know about?

Comment: like this? `object.functions['0'](object.parameters['0']['0']);`, you can easily convert it into a generic function, if you can see the pattern with the numbering :)

Comment: Can the items of _parameters_ not be _Arrays_?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424476/call-jquery-defined-function-via-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply loop over `object.functions`, and use `.apply` call it with its parameters from `object.parameters`.

```
for(var i in object.functions){
    if(object.functions.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        // Convert object.parameters[i] to an array
        var params = [];
        for(var j in object.parameters[i]){
            if(object.parameters[i].hasOwnProperty(j)){
                params.push(object.parameters[i][j]);
            }
        }
        // Call the function with an array of params
        window[object.functions[i]].apply(null, params);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, nice solution, I was about to comment on using `slice` with objects, haha

Comment: I tried doing `Array.prototype.slice.call(object.parameters[i])`, but it didn't work.  I think it needs a `.length` property to be able to do that.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that there is another _Object_ which holds references to the functions so that you're not looking in `window`, but other than that this is the way to go

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks for the answer. I haven't tested it yet but reading through your code I'm wondering, shouldn't I reset the params array in the end of the loop, after the window|object....]-line?

Comment: @Weblurk: What do you mean by "reset the params array"?  It's set to `[]` each time the outer loop (`object.functions`) runs.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Thought it was set outside the loop for some reason.

Comment: It's alright :-)  Glad I could be of assistance :-D